# Polish characters in a pdf file not rendered correcly in evince

Tags: fonts, pdf, evince, poppler

I've received a pdf invoice document containing Polish characters and I cannot render it properly using `evince`. The problem is related to the font settings. `pdffonts` show me this:

```
$ pdffonts test.pdf 
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
EDWAAA+HelveticaNeue-Roman           CID TrueType      Custom           yes yes yes      8  0
EDWAAB+Helvetica75Roman              CID TrueType      Custom           yes yes yes      7  0
ArialMT                              Type 1            WinAnsi          no  no  yes      9  0
```

Since I didn't have ArialMT font I've downloaded it from [here](https://www.dafontfree.net/freefonts-arial-mt-f111260.htm) and now I have it correctly cached:

```
$ fc-match ArialMT
ARI.ttf: "Arial MT" "Regular"
```

Then I've checked and confirmed installed font correctly displays Polish characters by choosing it in LibreOffice.

Despite this fonts are rendered like this:

[image]

This looks like a problem with Poppler because I can render it correctly with `mupdf` and Firefox:

[image]

`okular` and `qpdfview` fail just like `evince`.

I've downloaded the most recent version of Poppler from [here](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) and installed with:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
make install
```

But the problem remain the same. Not sure if evince is using it, though, since I don't see it its shared dependencies

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/evince | grep -i poppler
$
```

How can I use force `evince` to correctly display this font?

Answer (score 1):

Try Install MS TrueType Fonts as shown below:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Microsoft’s End user agreement wizard will appear. Click OK to continue.

After installing the fonts, you need to update the font cache using command:

```
$ sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

Alternatively, copy all Windows fonts to /usr/share/fonts directory and install the fonts using the following commands:

```
$ mkdir /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts
cp /Windowsdrive/Windows/Fonts/* /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts
$ chmod 755 /usr/share/fonts/WindowsFonts/*
```

Finally, regenerate the fontconfig cache using command:

```
$ fc-cache
```

Instruction is from: https://www.ostechnix.com/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-ubuntu-16-04/